# How to get excel sheet name in Python using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

Please see the code below.

```
def getSheetName(file_name):
    pointSheetObj = []
    import xlrd as xl
    TeamPointWorkbook = xl.open_workbook(file_name)
    pointSheets = TeamPointWorkbook.sheet_names()

    for i in pointSheets:
        pointSheetObj.append(TeamPointWorkbook.sheet_by_name(i))
```

I need to get the name of the excel sheet name from the list `pointSheetObj`by iterating it.

Comment: where did `pointSheetObj` come from?

Comment: I have taken it as a list to append the sheetnames

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the question? looks like you already got the names

Comment: I want to extract sheet name from `pointSheetObj `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have modified the code I gave as a question and have got what I needed actually,

```
def getSheetName(file_name):
    pointSheetObj = []
    import xlrd as xl
    TeamPointWorkbook = xl.open_workbook(file_name)
    pointSheets = TeamPointWorkbook.sheet_names()

    for i in pointSheets:
        pointSheetObj.append(tuple((TeamPointWorkbook.sheet_by_name(i),i)))
```

so if the list (of `tuple`) `pointSheetObj` is iterated we have name of the sheet at `index 1` of the `tuple` inside the `pointSheetObj`.

By doing this I have got the name and the worksheet object with which I can carry on with other sheet related methods.