# Combine Multiple Excel sheets within Workbook into one sheet Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

So I have 1500 Excel Workbooks, each with 10+ sheets with exactly same structure.
I tried to combine Multiple Excel Workbooks into one file and succeeded using code below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel('Combined_Excels.xlsx')
```

[image: 1pic]
And as a result I get combined Excel Workbook, but only with 1st sheets(pages) of each Excel Workbook.
I figured that I need to add a parameter `sheet_name=None`, but this way my dataframe becomes a `dict` type and when appended, the result is not quite what I wanted.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel('Combined_Excels.xlsx')
```

[image: 2pic]
Have you guys had similar problems? How can I at least combine all sheets into one? Combining Multiple Excel Sheets would not be a problem imo as the first sample worked perfectly.

Thanks,
Nurbek

Comment: I am about to do exactly the same project. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24179378/6692898)

Comment: Shouldn't you define the Sheet every time you load a dataset, so that you will finally get all Sheets from every Workbook? Irrespective of the dict issue, with Sheet=None you will not achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You might find a better and more efficient ways to solve this problem, but this is how I did it:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


# First, combine all the pages in each Workbook into one sheet
cwd = os.path.abspath('')
files = os.listdir(cwd)
df_toAppend = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df_toAppend = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
        df_toAppend.to_excel(file)


# And then append all the Workbooks into single Excel Workbook sheet

cwd_2 = os.path.abspath('') 
files_2 = os.listdir(cwd_2)  
df_toCombine = pd.DataFrame()
for file_2 in files_2:
    if file_2.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df_toCombine = df_toCombine.append(pd.read_excel(file_2), ignore_index=True) 
        df_toCombine.to_excel('Combined_Excels.xlsx')
```

With Large sets of data, it may take considerable amount of time to combine.
Hope this helps someone eventually.