# How to run a python code for large inputs

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, random, parameters

In my code,

1. ```
    Samp_size
   ```
2. ```
    MSI
   ```
3. ```
    MRI
   ```
4. ```
    M_ASRS
   ```
5. ```
    a_h
   ```
6. ```
    d_h
   ```
7. ```
    a_v
   ```
8. ```
    d_v
   ```
9. ```
    max_hor_vel
   ```
10. ```
    max_ver_vel
    ```

These are randomly generated parameters above.Each can all take different numbers of values, lets say each has 2 different value.
I print them as dataframes to an excel file each in different sheets.(sheet1,sheet2 etc.)
So I have 2^10 different parameter set. How can I print the all the solutions for all this parameter set in order to an excel file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to combine sheets into one single excel file, if so, the following post will solve your problem: [Combine Multiple Excel sheets within Workbook into one sheet Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398446/combine-multiple-excel-sheets-within-workbook-into-one-sheet-python)

The code from  **# And then append all the Workbooks into single Excel Workbook sheet** will help.